# How to set menu-bar and header both in one application?

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I have set header in collection view

[image]

and when I try to add menu bar to content page it set above the header how do I set menu bar  below header ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by usings the Shell.TitleView control. You can even access it from any content page.

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <controls:ContentTitleBar PageTitleText="Home" />
</Shell.TitleView>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft doc, `menu bar` is a container that presents a set of menus in a horizontal row, at the top of a desktop app, and it not provide a method to change its position. but you can use the `shell navigation` as a menu bar.